# Automation software with diverse capabilities

Tags: automation

My team and I want to automate as many of our processes as possible, ideally with one piece of automation software. We do a lot of scripting in SAS on a separate Unix server, so the software would have to be able to open BluezoneX (software we use to connect to the server), then open a unix terminal and execute commands, maybe even update parameters in individual SAS scripts before running if that’s possible. We also need to be able to do sftp retrieval in conjunction with running SAS scripts, so the automation software would need to be able to log into websites and navigate through menus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UIpath](https://www.uipath.com/product/platform)   They offer free and paid solutions to automate tasks. There are several other RPA solutions as well out there. Some are free and some are quite expensive.

I have heard good things about [Automation Anywhere](https://www.automationanywhere.com/digital-workforce) as well and they now have a community version.